# rviz global map error after local map load fail

Tags: rviz

**i want to solve Global status error without rebooting**

physical turtlebot4 has a global map, and loads it when called

```
ros2 launch turtlebot4_navigation slam.launch.py
```

normally it responds that lidar_link messages like:

```
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1702269635.999470718] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1702269635.562 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1702269636.107949375] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1702269635.685 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1702269636.193591543] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1702269635.819 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1702269636.309897040] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1702269635.943 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
```

but when i try local map loading with

```sh
$ ros2 launch turtlebot4_navigation localization.launch.py map:=/home/seungoffice/boss_frontdoor.yaml
```

and then launch again

```sh
$ ros2 launch turtlebot4_navigation slam.launch.py

seungoffice@seungoffice-ThinkPad-L15-Gen-1:~$ ros2 launch turtlebot4_navigation slam.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/seungoffice/.ros/log/2023-12-11-13-43-47-696325-seungoffice-ThinkPad-L15-Gen-1-2901
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [sync_slam_toolbox_node-1]: process started with pid [2902]
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1702269827.859957320] [slam_toolbox]: Node using stack size 40000000
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1702269827.875930583] [slam_toolbox]: Using solver plugin solver_plugins::CeresSolver
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1702269827.876070723] [slam_toolbox]: CeresSolver: Using SCHUR_JACOBI preconditioner.
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1702270200.850896703] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)

no sign of lidar_link in console, 

and rviz does not load global map 

Global status error : Frame [map] does not exist happens
```

[image]

i tried

```
map_server shutdown
```

but it didnt changed error status

rebooting linux made rviz work properly

**how to solve Global status error without rebooting?**